# Leftover pollen residue after cleaning car

Tags: cleaning

I recently washed my car for the first time in several weeks after spring pollen. Lots of tree pollen / leaves I was unable to get these stains off the car, any thoughts?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Try a clay bar for auto detailing.